# Read text from in Excel ActiveX TextBox with python's xlwings

Tags: python, excel, vba, activex, xlwings

I get this issue that I cannot figure out: I'm trying to convert some VB code to Python using the xlwings library. The line I'm trying to convert is the following:

```
Ttarget = Worksheets('Main').txtTmaxTarget.Value  'This is VB code
```

So, within an Excel Workbook is a Sheet called 'Main' containing a TextBox that as been inserted from the Developer ribbon -> Insert -> Active X Control -> Text Box. The Name of that TextBox (in properties) is txtTmaxTarget.

The code from VB works but unable to make Python xlwings access the text inside the TextBox (the TextBox is not empty in the worksheet). Here is the closest guess I came to get a result:

```
import xlwings as xw

@xw.sub
def mySub(): 
    Ttarget = xw.Book.caller().sheets('Main').shapes('txtTmaxTarget').text
```

But this fails as Ttarget is always None upon return no mater what I put in the TextBox. What is the proper way to access the content of the TextBox?

Comment: xlwings currently only handles the text property of Shape objects natively, but not of ActiveX Controls. That's why @Vityata's answer is the correct one (workaround via `api`, i.e. the underlying pywin32 object.

Answer (score 0):

This one reads the text:

```
import xlwings as xw
def print_text_box():
    book_name = r'C:\hardcoded-path\foo.xlsx'
    sheet_name = 'Main'
    wb = xw.Book(book_name)
    sht = wb.sheets[sheet_name]
    my_text = wb.sheets('Main').api.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Value
    print(my_text)
print_text_box()
```

Writing works the same way:

`wb.sheets('Main').api.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Value = "some random text"`